# Linq select match list from other list performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a class like this

```
public class Category 
{
   CategoryID
   List<Product> ProductList
}
public class Product 
{
   CategoryID
}
```

`List<Category>` around 15k row and `List <Product>` around 40k row. I'm doing with LINQ like this

```
CategoryList.ForEach(i =>
{
    i.ProductList = ProductList.Where(x => x.CategoryID == i.CategoryID).ToList();
});
```

I want to know there are any implement better performance for this. Data could increase or decrease in other case

Comment: Have you considered using a database over in memory collections?

Comment: I did, but it not good at all

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's silly to use parallelism, when a simple change to the algorithm can speed it up thousandfold. Assuming `CategoryID` has a decent implementation of `GetHashCode()` a dictionary/lookup has nearly `O(1)` lookup times compared to the `O(n)` time of scanning through a list.

Two possible approaches:

### Turn categories into a dictionary

Assuming categories have unique IDs you can use:

```
var categoryById = categories.ToDictionary(c => c.CategoryID);
foreach(var product in products)
{
    var category = categoryById[product.CategoryID];
    category.Products.Add(product);
}
```

This has runtime `O(products.Count + categories.Count)` and uses `O(categories.Count)` memory.

If categories don't start out with an empty list, you might need to create it.

### Turn products into a Lookup

```
var productsByCategory = products.ToLookup(product => product.CategoryID);
foreach(var category in categories)
{
    category.Products = products[category.CategoryID].ToList();
}
```

This has runtime `O(products.Count + categories.Count)` and uses `O(products.Count)` memory.

Since there are typically more products than categories, this approach will require more memory. On the other hand the lookup might remove the need to embed a list of products in the category object.

Comment: And when it go to 40k of categories and 1m2 of products I think this will consume a lot of memory

Comment: @user1392853 The first approach will use something like 1-2 MB for 40k categories. That's much smaller than the data you're already keeping in memory. You can use that dictionary whenever you need to lookup a category. Compare this to the other algorithms which are already slow for your current amount of data and will slow down by a factor of 70 when scaling up to the amounts you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: *Don't forget that Big-O notations only says how the complexity grows with respect to the size (etc) - it doesn't give any indication of the constant factors involved. That's why sometimes even a linear search for keys is faster than a dictionary lookup...* This is quote from Jon Skeet's comment about this matter that can be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908050/optimizing-lookups-dictionary-key-lookups-vs-array-index-lookups

Comment: @Fabjan Not sure how that's relevant here. The slightly bigger overhead of a dictionary lookup compared to a list lookup isn't even close to the advantage of not having to scan through 10k+ categories for each product.

Answer (score 5):

You can use  parallel implementation of LINQ - [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/Dd460688(v=VS.110).aspx). Usually PLINQ increases the speed of LINQ, because it's using all available cores more efficiently.

```
CategoryList.AsParallel().ForAll(i =>
     {
         i.ProductList = ProductList.AsParallel.Where(x => x.CategoryID == i.CategoryID).ToList();
     });
```

Comment: It's pretty silly to parallelize inefficient code running in O(n*m) when a small change running in O(n+m) would result in a thousandfold improvement in performance.

Comment: Well, I must admit, `ToLookUp` is better variant. `Dictionary` isn't suitable, because ID doesn't unique. Didn't know about this class, thank you for notice.

Comment: CategoryID isn't unique among products, but it's probably unique among categories. So you can turn the categories into a dictionary. And of course a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` can function as a lookup (useful if you need a mutable lookup, since .NET only ships with an immutable lookup).

Comment: PLINQ also has the "downside" of being unordered by default, which might be an issue.  There's a few other things that can effect whether or not it's actually faster, although `Where` can be trivially parallelized.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a `GroupJoin` instead of multiple `where`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx

While Parallel will offer you up to nb core enhancement, you can obtain a linear complexity with GroupJoin.

From @CodesInChaos

> If the number of categories and products are on the same scale, you'll get a speedup from quadratic to linear runtime

Comment: "GroupJoin can provide exponential boost." Since the original algorithm has polynomial runtime an exponential speedup is impossible. If the number of categories and products are on the same scale, you'll get a speedup from quadratic to linear runtime.

Comment: I thought it would be *from quadratic to n*log(n)*. How is it linear ?

Comment: Typically we consider a lookup in a hash table as O(1) despite the potential complications. O(log(n)) lookup is typical for ordered/tree-based lookup tables. But the distinction between O(1) and O(log(n)) is rather academic, since logarithms grow so slowly.

Answer (score 3):

You may gain performance when organizing the product list grouped per category such as `Dictionary<int, List<Product>>`. You will then only have to pick the category's product list by its key instead of executing a LINQ query over the whole product list and generating new sub-lists.

```
CategoryList.ForEach(i =>
{
    i.ProductList = ProductDict[i.CategoryID];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

After testing performance i found out that better solution than one i posted before  is this :

```
    static List<Category> FilterList(List<Category> list, List<Product> ProductList)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, list.Count, i =>
        {
            list[i].ProductList = new List<Product>();
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < ProductList.Count; i2++)
                if (ProductList[i2].CategoryID == list[i].CategoryID) list[i].ProductList.Add(ProductList[i2]);
        });            

        return list;
    }
```

And then `list = FilterList(list, products);`

For `3,500,000` operations it took only `200ms`

Comment: It's like @Artem answear.

Comment: @user1392853 my answer uses `Parallel.For` and not Linq

Comment: Thanks for your suggest

Comment: 1) This still has quadratic runtime. 2) Using a second parallel for is probably slower than using a sequential `for`. The outer parallel for should already provide all the parallelism you need, with the inner only adding overhead.

Comment: Your code isn't even thread-safe since you're adding to a `List<T>` from multiple threads. So the inner `Parallel.For` *incorrect* and not just useless/inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Actually most efficient solution in such case would be creation of CategoryList from ProductList. Something like this:

```
CategoryList = ProductList
  .GroupBy(p=>p.CategoryID)
  .Select(
    g=>
      new Category{
        CategoryID=g.Key,
        ProductList = g.ToList()
      }
  );
```

Comment: there are more than only one property in CategoryList

Comment: Then you should use GroupJoin.

Answer (score 2):

If CategoryList already exists, you can first groupd the products by CategoryID, and then join the grouped products with the categories.

```
var query =
    from p in ProductList
    group p by p.CategoryID
        into grouped        
    join c in CategoryList
        on grouped.Key equals c.CategoryID
    select new { c, grouped };
```

Then use a loop to set the ProductList field of the Category objects.

```
foreach (var item in query)
    item.c.ProductList = item.grouped.ToList();
```